# Hierarchical data table for JSF2 and RichFaces

Tags: java, jsf, datatable, richfaces, treetable

I'm using RichFaces on my JSF2 application, and I need a way to have something like a tree-column or tree-table.

As far as I know, there's no support for such thing in RichFaces. Something's mentioned for RichFaces 4.0, but the priority of this in their plan isn't promising at all, and I don't think that it's going to be included in 4.0.

I know there's a tree table available in IceFaces, but I'd rather not add another library to avoid conflicts and learning curve and ...

So, I'm looking for the simplest way that I can achieve the same results with minimum efforts, maybe using sub-tables in RichFaces? Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Someone has written a tree table component before. May be useful for you. Take a look at [here](http://kubek2k.w.ds14.agh.edu.pl/wiki/doku.php?id=programming%3ajava%3arichfaces%3atreetable).

Comment: Thanks to point that out. I'll wait to see if there will be any more replies, but I'm not hoping so...

Comment: This is not quite what I was looking for, but seems this is the only solution out there, or that I need to implement my own / use IceFaces or other components.

Answer (score 0):

[link text](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/treeTableHome.jsf)

In the next version (coming in a few weeks) it will have more features